# Import Data from MS Excel using Java Source Code

Tags: java, excel

I want to Import data placed in MS Excel and print it using Java Application Program. I am newbie in Java. So Please guide, is it possible.

If yes, how? Any website/tutorial will be of great help..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [POI library](http://poi.apache.org/index.html) for reading from excel files

Comment: We use POI as well in our shop, it's quirky, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the jexcel APIs. They're quite simple overall. http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/

I also think that Apache POI is working on this area as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article on using [JDBC using Excel as a data source](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2001-06/04-qa-0629-excel.html)

Comment: Also, one more thing. This kind of connectivity will work only when u are using single PC.. But when you need to design a web-based application i.e. using Servlets or JSP than these settings won't work?? Does there exist any Java package? Please forward that...

Answer (score 0):

Why not export it from Excel in some format that is not proprietary? If the data is not too complex, even CSV might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**This JSP page connects the Excel sheet to the database .**

```
.<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %><br/>
.<% Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"); %>

<BODY>               

.<%
  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DsnName");<br/>
  Statement stm=con.createStatement();<br/>
  ResultSet rs=stm.executeQuery("select * from [Sheet1$]");       
%>

.<% if(!rs.next()) {
    out.println("Sorry, could not find data");
 }
 else { %>
  .<%=rs.getString(1)%>
.<%}%>

</BODY>
```